# Elasticsearch \ logstash stopped accepting specific documents

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to figure out something that happened to me just today, where Elasticsearch suddenly refuses to accept certain documents from logstash.
latest versions of both (2.2.0 and 2.2.2)

this is the error i get in logstash:

```
"error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Can't merge a non object mapping [body.xxx] with an object mapping [body.xxx]"}}}
```

this is thee same thing from ES logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't merge a non object mapping [body.message.sender] with an object mapping [body.message.sender]
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your mapping and the document(s) you think is causing this issue?

Comment: not exactly sure what to look for... I have a huge mapping that is created dynamically by logstash sending new fields

Comment: I think that the issue is somewhere with the "body" field, which is actually mapped as an "object". now it seems to be OK, since we do send documents with body.x and body.y and many more under it (i'm guessing that this is the way ES indexes those kinds of data...)

Comment: what other info can i provide?

Comment: For starters, maybe the current existing mapping for the body field. Then we'll look into your documents to be indexed, to see if there's a body field containing a conflicting `message.sender` value/type.

Comment: well its mapped as an object..  "body": { "type": "object" }

Comment: perhaps i'm looking for the wrong thing?

Comment: There should be some inner fields in there. Can you run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` and update your question with the results you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105499/discussion-between-benyamin-d-and-val).

Comment: According to our chat discussion, you should not have an empty body in your document, i.e. `body: {}`, try to make body null instead when there's no content, i.e. `body: null`